# Open neighborhood of a point on a graph.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous function, $S \subseteq X$ a dense subset, $Y$ is Hausdorff. Let $V=V_1 \times V_2$ be an open neighborhood of $(x,f(x))$. Since $S$ is dense in $X$, the intersection $S \cap V_1$ is non-empty. So there exists a $y \in S \cap V_1$. Now, is it necessarily true that $f(y) \in V_2$ (or maybe, $f(y) \in f(S) \cap V_2$)?

I think it's true (by the logic that if $y$ is close to $x$ then $f(y)$ is close to $f(x)$ since $f$ is continuous) but I'm having difficulty proving or disproving this.
This is one step in my attempt to prove that the closure of the graph of $f \restriction_S$ in $X \times Y$ equals the graph of $f$. I am trying to show that all open neighborhoods of a point $(x,f(x))$ on the graph of $f$ intersect the graph of $f \restriction_S$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(y)\not\in V_2$ for all $y\in S$. Note that $x\in f^\leftarrow[V_2]$ (an open set by continuity of $f$), but $y\not\in f^\leftarrow[V_2]$ for all $y\in S$. Thus $x$ is not in the closure of $S$, so $S$ is not dense.

Comment: I think in the question you also want $y \in V_1$, but this is easy to fix by replacing $f^{-1}(V_2)$ by $f^{-1}(V_2) \cap V_1$.